# Parametric ajax request body

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to plug in or plug out the data part of an ajax request body. Let's say I have an ajax body like this;

```
"ajax": {
            "url": `/${controllerName}/${actionName}`,
            "type": "POST",
            "data": {example : values},
            "datatype": "json"
        }
```

I want to be able to add or remove the `data` part of this ajax body **conditionally**. I tried something like this;

```
"ajax": {
            "url": `/${controllerName}/${actionName}`,
            "type": "POST",
            exampleCondition == true ? ("data": {example : values}) : "",
            "datatype": "json"
        }
```

But it obviously did not work. I couldn't came up with an idea how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe have a data variable else that changes before performing the ajax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to expand an object into its properties. By combining this syntax with a ternary operator, you can conditionally add new properties to an object in a concise way.

For example, having a false condition:

```js
const exampleCondition = false;
const ajax = {
  url: "http://test.com",
  type: "POST",
  datatype: "json",
  ...(exampleCondition ? {data: {example : 'example'}} : {})
};

console.log(ajax);
```

And an example having a true condition:

```js
const exampleCondition = true;
const ajax = {
  url: "http://test.com",
  type: "POST",
  datatype: "json",
  ...(exampleCondition ? {data: {example : 'example'}} : {})
};

console.log(ajax);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that simply using the conditional code outside your javascript object.

```
var ajax = {
  "url": `/${controllerName}/${actionName}`,
  "type": "POST",
  "datatype": "json"
}

if(exampleCondition == true) {
    ajax.data = {example: values2}
}
```